# Estimote beacon is not detected with latest library of altbeacons 2.19.4

Tags: android, kotlin, ibeacon, altbeacon, estimote

I am using altbeacon library with verison("2.19.4") for getting the estimoate beacons.
Doing some R&D and getting the

```
 m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24
```

above layout to set on Beacon parser class. I put this code on Beacon parser class and assign to beacon manager.

```
 val beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.clear()
        val parser = BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(parser)
        val region = Region("com.beacon", null, null, null)
        // Set up a Live Data observer so this Activity can get monitoring callbacks
        // observer will be called each time the monitored regionState changes (inside vs. outside region)
        beaconManager.getRegionViewModel(region).rangedBeacons.observe(this, rangingMonitorObserver)s
        beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)

 private val rangingMonitorObserver = Observer<Collection<Beacon>> { beacons ->
        Log.d("HomeFragment TAG", "Ranged: ${beacons.count()} beacons")
        for (beacon: Beacon in beacons) {
            Log.d("HomeFragment TAG", "$beacon about ${beacon.distance} meters away")
        }
    }
```

I execute this code but did not get the beacons.
Does Anyone Know How to get the estimote beacon using the alt beacon library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before troubleshooting your code, let's make sure the beacon is detectable with off-the-shelf tools that are known to detect iBeacon.  I suggest downloading BeaconScope from the Google Play Store (based on the Android Beacon Library), and verifying it detects your Estimote.    If it does not detect it, there may be a problem with the beacon or its settings.

Comment: While not shown in your code, make sure you have obtained FINE_LOCATION permission from the user in your app.  Android apps cannot start bluetooth scans without obtaining that permission.

Comment: @davidgyoung I downloaded the app and try to scan the beacon it's detected.
On My app, I add the location and Bluetooth permissions before scanning I provide the permissions. but on my side, it's not detected.

Comment: @davidgyoung Is there a need to change the set beacon layout?

Comment: The beacon layout you show is correct.  The code shown looks correct.  You might try the reference app and confirm it works.  If so, look for differences between your code and its code of simply use the reference app as a starting point.  https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library-reference-kotlin

Comment: @davidgyoung do you know why the below error comes and how to resolve this?
E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Scan failed: app cannot be registered

Comment: That log line is an indication that Android is refusing to allow a Bluetooth scan to start.  That is almost always caused by the proper permissions not being granted to the app.  The Android error code returned is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback#SCAN_FAILED_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION_FAILED

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possible causes of failed beacon detections.  One of the most common causes is if **your app doesn't have the proper permissions from Android for Bluetooth scanning.**   The specific permissions needed vary depending on the `targetSdkVersion` setting in your build.gradle file:

```
targetSdkVersion      Android Version     Permissions Needed
----------------      ---------------     ------------------
31                    12+                 BLUETOOTH_SCAN
                                          ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                                          BLUETOOTH (install time)
                                          BLUETOOTH_ADMIN (install time)

29-30                 10-11               ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                                          BLUETOOTH (install time)
                                          BLUETOOTH_ADMIN (install time)

15-18                 6-9                 ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                                          BLUETOOTH (install time)
                                          BLUETOOTH_ADMIN (install time)           

13-14                 4-5                 BLUETOOTH (install time)
                                          BLUETOOTH_ADMIN (install time)
```

Note that most of the above permissions (other than ones suffixed with "install time") are runtime permissions which require writing code to prompt the user to grant them.  If the user fails to grant them, or the permission are later lost or reverted, the scans won't work.

In addition to the above, if you want to detect beacons when the app is in the background (no activity visible on the screen) you must also have ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission on Android 10+ (targetSdkVersion 29 or higher).

Writing code to obtain these permissions can be tricky.  The easiest way to confirm you have obtained them is to go to Settings -> Apps -> Your app name -> Permissions

Be aware that the names in the permissions screen are slightly different than the declared permissions in the manifest as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Read my blog post [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2021/08/07/nag-os) for more info on how we got here.